# Cast object from listview to another object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, casting, listviewitem

I have AnimalModel program I am stuck with.
The program contains an Abstract class Animal with subclasses Mammal, Insect, Bird, Reptile and  Marine. In every subclass there also two more sublclasses of animals.

For example, Mammal have the classes Wolf and Dog.

My problem is that i have created an method for adding animal items to an array.

I'm trying to cast an object in a listview containing  for example  wolf or dog to a Mammal object without success..

I've tried in two ways both none of them works..

```
private void AddAnimalItem() 
{
    string m_age = txtAge.Text;
    string m_Name = txtName.Text;

    CategoryType m_CategoryType = (CategoryType)(lstCtgr.SelectedIndex);
    Animals animal = null;

    switch(m_CategoryType)
    {
        case CategoryType.Mammal:

            // first attempt
            Mammal mammalspecies  = (Mammal)Enum.Parse(typeof(Mammal),
                                        lstAnml.SelectedItem.ToString());

            // second attempt
            Mammal mammalspecies = lstAnimal.SelectedItems.Cast<Mammal>();

            // Static method for creating an Mammal to an animal
            animal = Mammal.MammalFactory(mammalspecies);
            break;
    }

    /* ... */
 }
```

Comment: You should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11713043/edit) and add a tag corresponding to the language / environment you are using.

Comment: Could you possibly show us the definition of the type "Mammal"?  From what I can read, it looks like Mammal might be an Enum, whereas Animal appears to be a class.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What error do you get? Compiler error? Exception? Please clarify which types are `classes` and which ones are `enumns`.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to people trying to help you with this if you provide all the code involved; preferrably provide a small but complete example that shows the problem you are having.  Dumping your code on SO and noting "without success" won't generally get you useful answers, just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest many things for this code, the least of which is:

1. With lstCtgr don't cast an ordinal to another type (enum, I assume), I would clear a list item class that contains the textual representation of an item (ToString) and and ability to get the actual CategoryType independently from the order of the list.
2. I would do something similar with lstAnimal.  If you need to get information about what is selected beyond it's ordinal, I would create class that you can add to lstAnimal that gives you that information.  Much like lstCtr, at type that implements ToString and provides access to a Mammal object.

But, it's extremely unclear what you need to do or even what you're trying to do with the code that you've posted.  It doesn't make sense that you'd both select a category of animal (lstCtgr) **and** an actual animal (lstAnml).  What the animal is in in lstAnml seems completely independent of lstCtr.

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide more information for your question. Since you haven't provided enough information, I need to make a few assumptions:-

- `Mammal` is a class, not an enum. (Because enums cannot have subclasses or sub-enums.)
- `CategoryType` is an enum, not a class, but one of its values is also called *Mammal* (ie. `CategoryType.Mammal`).
- `lstAnml` is a *ListBox*, and its values are strings that are the **fully-qualified** class names of the Mammal subclasses (eg. `"MyNamespace.Wolf"`, `"MyNamespace.Dog"`).
- `Mammal`, `Wolf`, and `Dog` classes all have *parameterless* constructors.

If my above assumptions are wrong, please update your question with the missing information.

If my above assumptions are correct, then replace your first/second attempt with the following:-

```
Type mammaltype = Type.GetType(lstAnml.SelectedItem.ToString());
Mammal mammalspecies = (Mammal) Activator.CreateInstance(mammaltype);
```

However, your last statement's logic seems to be wrong. `Mammal.MammalFactory()` should be taking in an *enum* as a parameter, not a class instance. But if `Mammal` really is an enum, then it cannot have subclasses...

So assuming `Mammal` really is a class, not an enum, then your last statement should simply be:

```
animal = mammalspecies;
```